# Ignoring leading whitespace in the "lazy-text" quasiquoter in Haskell Text.Shakespeare.Text

Tags: haskell, yesod, shakespeare-text

I am writing a Haskell command line program and using the `lt` quasiquoter ("lazy-text") from `Text.Shakespeare.Text`. In the [Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book), it says that the `hamlet` quasiquoter ignores leading whitespace if the first non-whitespace character is a backslash (`\`).

Does this work in the `lt` quasiquoter?

My code looks like this:

```
[lt|Usage: #{programName} [OPTION ...]
   \Version #{showVersion version}|]
```

but the output is

```
Usage: MyProg [OPTION ...]
    \Version 0.1.0.0
```

with the `Version` string indented too far (and still containing the backslash). I also tried it with a space between the backslash and `V`.

Is this possible with shakespeare-text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear to, however it isn't hard to add the feature yourself. `lt` is just a `QuasiQuoter`, which is the data type:

```
QuasiQuoter {
   quoteExp :: String -> Q Exp
 , quotePat :: String -> Q Pat
 , quoteType :: String -> Q Type
 , quoteDec :: String -> Q [Dec]
}
```

They take a `String`, and return the appropriate template haskell type (depending on the context it is used in.

It is a simple matter to transform a string so it works as you described with a regex:

```
stripWhiteSpaceBeforeBackslash :: String -> String
stripWhiteSpaceBeforeBackslash str = subRegex (mkRegex "^[[:space:]]*\\\\") str ""
```

Also, a function that transforms a `QuasiQuoter` with a string transform function is simple:

```
transformQuasiQuoter :: (String -> String) -> QuasiQuoter -> QuasiQuoter
transformQuasiQuoter transform quasi = QuasiQuoter {
    quoteExp = (quoteExp quasi) . transform
  , quotePat = (quotePat quasi) . transform
  , quoteType = (quoteType quasi) . transform
  , quoteDec =  (quoteDec quasi) . transform
  }
```

Now you can make a version of `lt` that does what you need:

```
lt_ = transformQuasiQuoter stripWhiteSpaceBeforeBackslash lt
```

Using it works as expected:

```
programName = "SomeProgram"
showVersion _ = "42.42.42"
version = 34

x = [lt_|Usage: #{programName} [OPTIONS...]
        \Version #{showVersion version}|]
```

`x` evaluates to `"Usage: SomeProgram [OPTIONS...]\nVersion 42.42.42"` in ghci.

Comment: Very nice! And it still does the evaluation at compile-time.